# How to concat three columns if they are not blank and also do a unique in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate 3 fields which hold user names and separate them with a comma, but only if they are not blank. And at end looking for unique names.

I found a function CONCAT_WS which will concat check for NULL and not blank.

```
Example:
Input : A B C => A,B,C
Input : A '' C => A,C
Input : A C C => A,C
```

Would you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONCAT_WS(',',NAME_COL1, IF(NAME_COL2, IF(NAME_COL2!=NAME_COL1,NAME_COL2,NULL),NULL),IF(NAME_COL3, IF(NAME_COL3!=NAME_COL1,NAME_COL3,NULL),NULL))
```

Comment: What if col3 = col2 ?? Also, If Col2 = Col1 then it will be formated as `,A,,C` which is not what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT t.`id`,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.cols SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (SELECT `id`,col1 as cols FROM YourTable where col1 is not null and col1 <> ''
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id`,col2 as cols FROM YourTable where col2 is not null and col2 <> ''
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id`,col3 as cols FROM YourTable where col3 is not null and col3 <> '' ) t
GROUP BY t.`id`
```

Comment: The last closing bracket is missing. The name are not separated by comma. And duplicates are not filtered correctly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50388/3 Have fun fixing that :-)

Comment: Or, just saying... I won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize your table on the fly and then use `group_concat`:

```sql
select id, group_concat(username order by username) as userlist
from (
    select distinct t.id, 
        case 
            when n.i = 1 then t.user1
            when n.i = 2 then t.user2
            when n.i = 3 then t.user3
        end as username
    from table1 t
    cross join (select 1 i union all select 2 union all select 3) n
    having username <> ''
) normalized
group by id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89281/2

Here's another one which orders the user names by columns instead of names:

```sql
select t.*, group_concat(distinct 
    case 
        when n.i = 1 and t.user1 <> '' then t.user1
        when n.i = 2 and t.user2 <> '' then t.user2
        when n.i = 3 and t.user3 <> '' then t.user3
    end
    order by n.i
) as userlist
from table1 t
cross join (select 1 i union all select 2 union all select 3) n
group by t.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/384e96/1